# Употребление времен

Tags: стилистика

Можно ли в одном предложении употреблять настоящее и прошедшее время? Задумалась, когда хотела поставить запятую и что-то покоробило.

Войны здесь выступали в качестве рэкета и об этом красноречиво пишут сами западные генералы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь разные времена вполне оправданны. Генералы пишут сейчас о том, что войны в прошлом выступали в качестве рэкета

Comment: Спасибо. У меня просто какой-то заскок. А запятую надо ставить, естественно?

Comment: Конечно, нужно

Answer (score 2):

Разные времена-то можно. Вот "войны в качестве рэкета" – категорически нельзя. Да ещё и "выступали".

"Красноречиво пишут" – тоже ой.

Answer (score 0):

"Войны выступали в качестве рэкета". А почему это "категорически нельзя"?

Из словаря: В качестве кого-чего. в зн. предлога.В роли, на правах; в виде. Ему пришлось выступить в качестве переводчика. Использовать в качестве мебели.

Примеры

внимание и речь выступали в качестве «предпосылок интеллекта»;

числа выступали в качестве «фоновых раздражителей»;

эти понятия у античных мыслителей выступали в качестве взаимозаменяемых терминов;

некоторые сотрудники выступали в качестве своего рода «источников повышенной опасности».

Comment: Здесь семантика страдает, не грамматика. Что такое рэкет и что такое война.

Comment: Чтобы разобраться в семантике, недостаточно прочесть одно предложение.